# i want to change my html select tag and jquery with select2 but it does not work

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

In my web site, i want to change my old select tag with select2 tokenization code. I tried lots of thing but i cant manage to post data as i posted before.

working scripts are here:

```
    <select multiple="true">
    <?
    $categories = ssDB::get("SELECT * FROM catlist order by cat asc");
    foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
            <option class="yenikat" value="<?=$category->id?>" rel="<?=$category->id?>"> <?=$category->cat?></option>
    <? } ?>
    </select>

    <input type="hidden" id="cat" value="">

    <a class="btn egonder"><? _e("gönder"); ?></a>
```

working jquery that posting data:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

$('.yenikat').click(function(e) {
    if($("#cat").val())
    var cat = $("#cat").val().split(',');
    else
    var cat = [];

    if($(this).is(':selected')) {
        cat.push($(this).attr("rel"));
    }
    else {
        var key = jQuery.inArray($(this).attr("rel"), cat);
        delete cat[key];
    }

    cat = $.grep(cat,function(n){ return(n) });
    $("#cat").val(cat.join(",")+",");
});
});
 </script>
```

Now i want to use this with select2 tokenization.

I put this in my page:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".tokenizationSelect2").select2({
    placeholder: "girdi için uygun kategori seçiniz", //placeholder
    maximumSelectionLength: 5,
    tags: true,
    language: "tr",
    tokenSeparators: ['/',',',';'," "],
    createTag: function(params) {
            return undefined;
       }
 });
 });
 </script>
```

i added class to my select tag:

```
 <select class="tokenizationSelect2" multiple="true">
```

now i managed to use tokenization but it does not post any data. my old scripts not working with this addition. i need to send data like old one. and i am very new at jquery and i really dont know how can i manage it. please help me.

Comment: Does your select tag need an ID/Name?

Comment: old codes not need an id or a name. it works without them. my old jquery using "yenikat" class which in option tag and "cat" id which in input tag.

Comment: Very strange that - everything looks OK to me.